# Visual Leak Detector - File and line number not available

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory-leaks, mfc, visual-leak-detector

I am debugging an MFC program and have come to a point where I am trying to find and resolve memory leaks. First I tried the built-in leak detector in VC, but once I redefined the new operator I got lots of problems with redefinitions of "new" and errors.

Moved on to Visual Leak Detector. I have got it up and running and it seems to find the leaks, but it cannot seem to find the file and line numbers. This is what it looks like:

```
WARNING: Visual Leak Detector detected memory leaks!
---------- Block 2 at 0x0343F718: 67 bytes ----------
Call Stack:
0x00B88E2F (File and line number not available): program.exe!for__get_vm + 0x1F bytes
0x00B8FC28 (File and line number not available): program.exe!for_rtl_init_wrap_ + 0x118 bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crt0dat.c (873): MSVCR100D.dll!_initterm
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (473): program.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0xF bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (371): program.exe!wWinMainCRTStartup
0x7540338A (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12 bytes
0x77819F72 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63 bytes
0x77819F45 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36 bytes

Data:
43 3A 5C 50    72 6F 6A 65    63 74 5C 50    72 6F 70 63     ........ ........
61 6C 63 5C    53 65 6B 6F    6E 64 65 6E    54 72 75 6E     ........ ........
6B 5C 77 42    6C 61 64 65    45 64 5C 2E    5C 44 65 62     .Random. .Symbols
75 67 5C 77    42 6C 61 64    65 45 64 2E    65 78 65 00     ........ ........
CD CD CD                                                     ........ ........
```

Having checked the FAQ on the Visual Leak Detector (VLD) website, there is a section stating that if this error occurs, then it may be so that VLD cannot find the debug symbols located in programname.pdb, since it must be situated alongside the programname.exe file. I have checked (and rebuilt), making sure that my project has the "Generate Debug Symbols" option turned on and that the programname.exe file gets created and put next to the programname.exe file in the debug folder.

Still, I refuses to show me the file and line numbers. 
Also, at the very top of my "output window" in Visual Studio i can see the following line:

```
'Program.exe': Loaded 'C:\Project\Program\Debug\Program.exe', Symbols loaded.
```

So, the symbols are loaded?
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using [Application Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371695(v=vs.85).aspx).  Not only will it find memory leaks, but, it will indicate other potential problems like heap corruptions.

Comment: @rrirower Okay, I shall try it out. Thanks!